# How to add and get sales by month in php?

Tags: php

I want to get the sales of the month in a table. But it is showing last order of the month and I want in my table January to December the sales will show in Total. Like In January I got 4 oreder each $10 then It will show january Sale : $40 not $10 last order. For this I am doing:

```
$thisyear = $db->query("SELECT total_Price,order_date FROM orderTable WHERE YEAR(order_date) = '{$thisyear}'");

  $current = array();
  $currentTotal = 0;

 while($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($thisyear)){
 $month = date("m-d-Y",strtotime($x['order_date']));
 if (!array_key_exists($month,$current)) {
  $current[(int)$month] = $x['total_Price'];

 }else{
   $current[$month] += $x['total_Price'];
   echo $current[$month]; // Here is the problem. This is not adding here like January = $40
 }
 $currentTotal += $x['total_Price'];
 }
```

I want to add all the earning of the month and want to show the month by month. And at the end $currentTotal is the total earning of the year.

Comment: You need to provide your basic table structure. With some sample data in it. And expected output

Comment: the key `$month` for $current includes the day (`$month = date("m-d-Y,..."`), while you only want the Year & month (``$month = date("Y-m, strto..."``).

Comment: @jeff Yes I guess you caught the problem. How to solve it. I tried date("m") but not worked!

Comment: also you `echo $current[$month]` before the while loop has finished, so you will see it increasing. Add a `foreach($current as $month) ` or smth like that _after_ the while loop.

Comment: @Sarah You will also need the year, otherwise jan17 and jan18 will be put together.. _EDIT_: just saw, that you only query for one year, so you might aswell leave the year and just take the month.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you want to sum the sales in your SQL query rewriting it to:

```
$months = $db->query(sprintf("
SELECT SUM(total_Price) AS month_total,MONTH(order_date) AS month   
FROM orderTable 
WHERE YEAR(order_date) = '%s' 
GROUP BY MONTH(order_date)", 
$db->escape($thisyear)));
```

and then just output it into template, you'll have all months summed for given year.

Note that I added `$db->escape()` call to show you a hint to avoid SQL-injections. There may be different way to escape the variables injected into the query, but you definitely may want to use them - check your ORM or MySQL library doc.

Comment: good solution, won't need the Group by Year though, since we only query for one year.

Comment: Yes , thanks, for some reason I missed it . Edited my answer

Comment: using `sprintf` instead of prepared statements is not the best idea

Comment: Good, but the initial question uses some orm we don't know. How can I recommend using prepared statements (which are certainly better) if I don't know the library they use? I proposed to use some probably nonexistent `::escape()` call to avoid SQL injections to give them a hint.